# Error when setting dynamically created joints axis in Gazebo 1.8.0

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am using Gazebo 1.8.0, during the simulation I create dynamically joints between objects, but when I set their axis I get the following error (this used to work on older Gazebo versions):

```
Error [SDF.cc:761] Missing element description for [axis]
gazebo: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = sdf::Element]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

This happens when I use the `SetAxis()` function

```
math::Vector3 axis;
...
this->myJoint->SetAxis(0, axis);
```

Without it, the joint creation works without any problems.
I noticed a similar error in [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2387/drcsim-sdf-bug-prevents-roslaunch-from-working/) question, not sure if they are related, plus it says that it is fixed since release 1.6.3

UPDATE!!! (the working code, thanks to @scpeters, after adding the Load() function):

```
// create the joint for the given model
    this->myJoint = this->model->GetWorld()->GetPhysicsEngine()->CreateJoint("revolute",  this->model);

// attach joint to links
    this->myJoint->Attach(spatula_link, palm_link);

// load the joint, and set up its anchor point
    this->myJoint->Load(spatula_link, palm_link, math::Pose(spatula_link->GetWorldPose().pos, math::Quaternion()));

// set the axis of revolution
    this->myJoint->SetAxis(0, axis);

// set other joint attributes
    this->myJoint->SetAttribute("stop_cfm",0, this->stop_cfm);
    this->myJoint->SetAttribute("stop_erp",0, this->stop_erp);
    this->myJoint->SetAttribute("hi_stop",0, this->hi_stop);
    this->myJoint->SetAttribute("lo_stop",0, this->lo_stop);
```

Thanks,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2824/error-when-setting-dynamically-created-joints-axis-in-gazebo-1.8.0/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-14**:
Can you show a bit more code that you use for creating the joints? I think the order in which you call the functions matters. For example in [VRCPlugin::AddJoint](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/3998f2ecc32a0ee0776d329f23262aca7d9b1424/ros/atlas_msgs/VRCPlugin.cpp#cl-406), the order is joint = world->GetPhysicsEngine()->CreateJoint(), then joint->Attach(), then joint->Load(), then joint->SetAxis(), then eventually joint->Init().

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-05-15**:
Hey, thanks for the answer, It worked after I used the `Load()` function, but without `Init()` because then it sets some configured values to default ones. You should write your answer with the example link as an answer so I can mark it resolved. Cheers

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-15**:
If you don't mind posting what you did, I'll upvote it.

**Comment by [awesomebytes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/950/awesomebytes/) on 2016-04-19**:
I'm battling with this problem on this package: https://github.com/pal-robotics/gazebo_ros_link_attacher (self contained) I get a crash when linking two models, and it seems I'm doing it like everyone else. The crash is: ***** Internal Program Error - assertion (self->inertial != __null) failed in static void gazebo::physics::ODELink::MoveCallback(dBodyID):
/tmp/buildd/gazebo4-4.1.3/gazebo/physics/ode/ODELink.cc(178): Inertial pointer is NULL

**Comment by [awesomebytes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/950/awesomebytes/) on 2016-04-22**:
The package is finished with my bug solved, you can attach any two links of the simulation and later detach them: https://github.com/pal-robotics/gazebo_ros_link_attacher should work on gazebo 2, 4 & 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Answered in edited question.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0